# Can't center my custom header in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, header

I've added a custom header to my WordPress theme, and I cannot get it to center.  I want to set the position as bottom center, but no CSS I add will override it. What's the proper way to change the position?

Thanks!

http://www.meynedesign.com/floral

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code.
<div>
  <header class="site-header" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" style="width: 50%; margin: 37px auto 0px;">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="title-area">
        <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline">
          <a href="http://meynedesign.com/floral/">Floral Theme</a>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```